# How do I interpret this SML typing expression?

Tags: sml, typing

```
(* val bar = fn : (’a * ’b -> ’b) -> ’b -> ’a list -> ’b *)
fun bar f b nil = b
| bar f b (h::t) = f (h, bar f b t)
```

This function was given to us with the instructions of explaining what it does. The only further information given are that the parameters are a binary function, a value, and a list. From looking at it, I already know that if the list is nil, it returns the b value, otherwise it applies the binary function to the list head and recurses. I just don't understand how to interpret this line:

```
(* val bar = fn : (’a * ’b -> ’b) -> ’b -> ’a list -> ’b *)
```

There are numerous tutorials explaining SML's typing, but I can't find anything in-depth enough to apply to this. Could anyone translate it to English so I know how it works for future reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand this type sgnature, you need to first understand [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

A definition like

```
fun sum a b = a + b
```

has type `int -> int -> int`.

It is a function of *one* variable (an integer) where the return value is itself a function, one which sends ints to ints.

For example, `val f = sum 1` assigns to `f` the function which adds one to its input (in other words, the successor function) so that, e.g., `f 5` evaluates to 6.

In practice, such functions are often used like `sum 3 4` but what is happening there *isn't* the passing of 2 values to `sum`. Rather, the one value 3 is passed, which returns a function, and this returned value is then applied to 4. Thus, `sum 3 4` should be parsed as `(sum 3) 4` rather than `sum (3,4)` -- which would be a type error.

Note that this is fundamentally different from something like

```
fun add (a,b) = a + b
```

which *is* a function of two variables, it has type `int * int -> int`, which is different than sum's type of `int -> int -> int`. The latter is not syntactic sugar for the former, but instead has a fundamentally different semantics.

When reading something such as `int -> int -> int`, you should read it as right-associative. In other words, it is the same as `int -> (int -> int)`.

Another thing that is happening with `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b` is the use of *type variables* `'a, 'b`. This means that the type you are trying to parse is of a higher-order *polymorphic* function. It `'a` and `'b` can represent any type.

Putting it all together, a function, `f`, of type `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b` is a function which takes as input any function whose type is of the form `'a * 'b -> 'b` (a function of two variables whose return type is the type of the second variable). The return value of `f` is a function of the form `'b -> 'a list -> 'b`. This latter is a function which takes an element of type `'b` and returns a function which sends `'a lists` to objects of type `'b`

You could summarize it by saying that `f` is a *curried* function which takes a function of type `('a * 'b -> 'b)`, a value of type `'b`, a list of values of type `'a`, and returns a value of type `'b`. That is accurate enough, but don't slip into thinking of it as equivalent to a function of type

```
('a * 'b -> 'b) * 'b * 'a list -> 'b
```

By the way, two of the most useful functions in SML, `foldl` and `foldr` have type `('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b`, so this isn't merely an academic exercise. Being able to unpack such type descriptions is a key to being able to use such functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution based on what is apparently called type inferencing. I had never learned this before but

```
(* val bar = fn : (’a * ’b -> ’b) -> ’b -> ’a list -> ’b *)
```

is display of argument and return types for the function.

`(’a * ’b -> ’b)` refers to the first argument function. It requires 2 arguments (`'b` and `'a`) in itself and returns 1 value `'b`.

`'b` refers to the second argument, a value.

`'a list` refers to a list of values, the third argument in the function.

Finally, the last `'b` is the return value.

Comment: The function only takes a single argument (which itself is a function) so your use of the words "first", "second", etc. reflects a misunderstanding. Furthermore, the return value is a function of type `’b -> ’a list -> ’b`, not an element of type `b`.  Don't interpret a curried function as if it were non-curried.